# Track location change events using a gsm module

Tags: android, geolocation, gsm

I want to track location changes events using a gsm module. The main purpose is to save battery life do not using GPS when a user does not move. I've tried using `LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION` and `LISTEN_SIGNAL_STRENGTH`, but in this case even the phone does not move PhoneStateListener returns different cell locations areas and signals stregths.
Are the any gsm params to track location changes? I do not need an exact location, I need only a location change event.

Comment: Try using `LocationManager` method `requestLocationUpdates (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)` You can define the Criteria based on your application requirement.

Comment: the main purpose is to avoid using battery-consuming LocationManager while a phone doesn't move, and start using it when the phone starts moving

Comment: Sorry, but it seems a non sense. How can you know if users changes its position, without using a location manager?

Comment: 1. ActivityRecognizer 2...

Comment: Yes, but ActivityRecognizer is not accurate.

Comment: Yep, we should choose between accuracy and battery life

Comment: If you have wifi enabled at the time also that might give you another trigger and would generally be much more granular - i.e. detect smaller movements. You might get some 'noise' from WiFi dropping and coming back even when the user has not moved but it could be worth experimenting with.